# How to use the string.prototype.matchall polyfill?

Tags: javascript, shim

I want `String.prototype.matchAll()` method to be working in edge browser as well. So  thought of using [the "string.prototype.matchall" npmjs package](https://npmjs.com/package/string.prototype.matchall)

I have installed this package and imported in my `main.js` file like so

```js
import 'string.prototype.matchall';
```

I have to use this method in other file say `Input.js.` so I use like below

```js
const matchAll = require('string.prototype.matchall');
```

And in the method where this I actually match the strings is below

```js
replace = (original_string) => {
  const regex_pattern = /\\d+@*)]/g;
  const matchAll = require('string.prototype.matchall'); 
  const matches = original_string.matchAll(regex_pattern);
  return matches;
}
```

but `matchAll` variable is unused. How do I use this *string.prototype.matchall polyfill*. Could someone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the package implements the [*es-shim API*](https://github.com/es-shims/es-shim-api), you should call the `shim()` method...

> `require('foo').shim` or `require('foo/shim')` is a function that when invoked, will call `getPolyfill`, and if the polyfill doesn’t match the built-in value, will install it into the global environment.

This will let you use `String.prototype.matchAll()`.

```js
const matchAll = require('string.prototype.matchall')
matchAll.shim()

const matches = original_string.matchAll(regex_pattern)
```

Otherwise, you can use it stand-alone

> `require('foo')` is a spec-compliant JS or native function. However, if the function’s behavior depends on a receiver (a “this” value), then the first argument to this function will be used as that receiver. The package should indicate if this is the case in its README

```js
const matchAll = require('string.prototype.matchall')

const matches = matchAll(original_string, regex_pattern)
```

---

To use an ES6 module import, you would use something like this at the top of your script (**not** within your `replace` function)

```js
import shim from 'string.prototype.matchall/shim'
shim()
```

Comment: thanks....so in main.js use import statement like import 'string.prototype.matchall' and in the file where i get the matches use require('string.prototype.matchall')?

Comment: No, `require()` and `import` both do essentially the same thing. If the polyfill supports a default module export, you would use `import matchAll from 'string.prototype.matchall'`

Comment: i want to use import statement so how do i use export sorry new to programming.

Answer (score 8):

I used this, works for me. Looping through the matches of global flagged pattern did the trick. Let me know if you have any issue using it, I will be glad to help.

```
function matchAll(pattern,haystack){
    var regex = new RegExp(pattern,"g")
    var matches = [];
    
    var match_result = haystack.match(regex);
    
    for (let index in match_result){
        var item = match_result[index];
        matches[index] = item.match(new RegExp(pattern)); 
    }
    return matches;
}
```

Comment: Works great! Took me a while to figure that pattern passed in should not have global flag.

Comment: There is an issue with this implementation. item.match(new RegExp(pattern)) always returns an object with index: 0 since item is a matched string, the first match is always at index 0.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) **RegExp** method. Be aware that the RegExp pattern must use the global `g` flag to avoid an infinite loop.

```js
function matchAll(re, str) {
  let match
  const matches = []

  while (match = re.exec(str)) {
    // add all matched groups
    matches.push(...match.slice(1))
  }

  return matches
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code example from @Joe freezes the browser for me unfortunately.

I need this polyfill for an old browser that doesn't know a spread operator.

Here the helper function slightly modified with example:

```js
var str = 'my super <b>interesting</b> text is super <b>interesting</b>';

function matchAll(str, re) {
  re = new RegExp(re, 'g');
  var match;
  var matches = [];
  
  while (match = re.exec(str)) 
    matches.push(match);
    
  return matches;
}

console.log('log 1:', matchAll(str, 'interesting'));

(matchAll(str, 'interesting') || []).forEach(function(i) {
  // loop through matches and replace
  str = str.replace(i[0], 'boring')
});

console.log('log 2:', str);


// another usecase
console.log('log 3:', matchAll(str, '<b>(.+?)</b>'));

(matchAll(str, '<b>(.+?)</b>') || []).forEach(function(i) {
  // loop through matches and replace
  str = str.replace(i[0], '<u>' + i[1] + '</u>')
});

console.log('log 4:', str);
```