# Javascript Regex matchAll function not working

Tags: javascript, regex

whenever I run the code below I get en error `TypeError: responseData.matchAll is not a function`

```
    var responseData = response.data.toString(); 
    var regex = new RegExp('(<dbname>)(.*?)(?=<\/dbname>)', 'g'); 

    var matches = responseData.matchAll(regex);
```

When I replace `matchAll` with `exec` it works! However, I need to use `matchAll`. This is driving me crazy. Thanks

Comment: What does `console.log(responseData)` print?

Comment: Check the compatibility (the RegExp exec method is _much_ older, while matchAll requires a browser version “newer than Mid-ish 2019” or a polyfill): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need `matchAll`, use it if supported:

```js
var responseData = "<dbname>hhh</dbname>hhh<dbname>hhh3</dbname>"; 
var regex = new RegExp('<dbname>(.*?)(?=</dbname>)', 'g'); 
console.log(Array.from(responseData.matchAll(regex), x=>x[1]));
// => ["hhh","hhh3"]
```

You can also use `exec`:

```js
var responseData = "<dbname>hhh</dbname>hhh<dbname>hhh3</dbname>"; 
var regex = new RegExp('<dbname>(.*?)(?=</dbname>)', 'g'); 
while(match=regex.exec(responseData)){
  console.log(match[1]);
}
```

Comment: exec only returns the first result.

Comment: @PaulTrimor That is why it is in a `while` block.

Answer (score 1):

`matchAll` is pretty new, it only works in some browsers. It works in Chrome, FX, Edge and Safari, but older and mobile browsers may require a shim/polyfill.

Here is a good answer on using a shim to add the functionality to older browsers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58003501/905